# SCA/PSD2 compliant payment processor

Tags: extension, payment-processor, payment, payment-method

What is the current  SCA/PSD2 compliant  payment processor available, other than stripe? 
Having lot of issues with stripe recently and not being so reliable and looking for an alternative.

Note: SCA compliance is a requirement of the EU Revised Directive on Payment Services (PSD2) on payment service providers within the European Economic Area, described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_customer_authentication

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to update to the latest version of the stripe extension, quite a few things changed with SCA...

But for what it's worth, works fairly reliably for us

As for your question:

Paypal is SCA compliant (mostly because everything happens on their website, so they manage the confirmation step).

... but if you aren't keen on stripe, you might like paypal even less ;)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I am using latest version. But don’t you see uncaptured transactions often?

Comment: @Tapash Care to chime in on this issue? https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/issues/141

Comment: @Laryn-CEDC.org this issue was always there and still is since the 6.x was created. There’s refund function after 24hours but that is not a good solution. Because customers money is on hold and may not have enough funds to make another payments. And this issue gave me thought of looking for an alternative since it created extreme confusion for admins and donors. Developer says it’s impossible to fix this issue https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/issues/147

Comment: ah, what you mean by not working reliably is the uncaptured transaction? ok, I can see where you come from, but given how civicrm handle contribution forms, not sure how to workaround indeed.